# How do I create this using Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose

Download the repository to your local machine and unzip the directory. Enter the directory (you may rename the directory first) on command line environment, then use the following command to download the rails docker image and to build.

The repository file is been downloaded and unzipped it. What should I do

> docker-compose run web rails new . --force --no-deps --database=postgresql
>
> docker-compose build

ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

```
    Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `docker-compose.yml` file or `docker-compose.yaml`. Accordingly to documentation:

```
Using Compose is basically a three-step process:

1. Define your app’s environment with a Dockerfile so it can be reproduced anywhere.

2. Define the services that make up your app in docker-compose.yml so they can be run together in an isolated environment.

3. Run docker-compose up and Compose starts and runs your entire app.
```

A docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    - logvolume01:/var/log
    links:
    - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
volumes:
  logvolume01: {}
```

More on official [website](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)